# Merging vectors

Tags: c++, vector, merge

So far this is my code, what i am trying to do is say i input 1 2 3 for the fist vector and 
9 8 7 for the second vector, i want it do print our 1 9 2 8 3 7. but i cant figure it out, can someone point me onto the right direction. Thank you in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm> 
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

vector<int> append(vector<int> a, vector<int> b)
{
    int n = a.size();
    int m = b.size();
    vector<int> c(n + m);
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        c[i] = a[i];

    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
        c[n + i] = b[i];

    return c;
}

vector<int> merge(vector<int> a, vector<int> b) 
{
    int n = a.size();
    int m = b.size();
    vector<int> c(n + m);
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        c[i] = a[i];

    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
        c[n + i] = b[i];

    return c;
}

vector<int> merge_sorted(vector<int> a, vector<int> b)
{

    int n = a.size();
    int m = b.size();
    vector<int> c(n + m);
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        c[i] = a[i];

    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
        c[n + i] = b[i];

return c;
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Please enter a set of numbers, insert -1 when done.\n";
    vector<int>a;
    bool more = true;
    while (more)
    {
        int n;
        cin >> n;
        if (n == -1)
            more = false;
        else
            a.push_back(n);
   }


    cout << "Please enter another set of numbers, insert -1 when done.\n";
    vector<int>b;
    more = true;
    while (more)
   {   
        int m;
        cin >> m;
        if (m == -1)
        more = false; 
        else 
        b.push_back(m);
    }

   vector<int>d = append(a,b);
    {

        int i;
    cout << "Appended: ";
        for (i= 0; i < d.size(); i++)

        cout << d[i] << " ";
    cout << "\n";
}

vector<int>r = merge(a,b);
{
  cout << "Merged: ";

  vector<int> all_nodes(a.size() + b.size());

  sort(a.begin(), a.end());
      sort(b.begin(), b.end());

      merge(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), b.end(), all_nodes.begin());
  cout << "\n";
}

    vector<int>z = merge_sorted(a,b);
{

    a.insert( a.end(), b.begin(), b.end() );
    sort( a.begin(), a.end() );

        cout << "Sorted: ";

    for (vector<int>::iterator it = a.begin(); it != a.end(); ++it)
        cout << *it << " ";
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Assuming both the vectors of same size

vector<int> vec1;
vector<int> vec2;
vector<int> result;

vec1.push_back(1);
vec1.push_back(2);
vec1.push_back(3);

vec2.push_back(7);
vec2.push_back(8);
vec2.push_back(9);

int nsize = vec1.size();//Take any one vector;
int j = 0;
for(int i=0;i<nsize;i++)
{
  result.push_back(vec1[i]);
  result.push_back(vec2[i]);
}
```

Comment: This wouldn't work as written, result.size() is still zero.  You either need to change the loop to use `.push_back()` or call `result.resize(2*nsize);` before the loop.

Comment: do a push_back to result vec...

Answer (score 1):

Your merge code is **exactly** the same as your append code. How is that going to work? The other issue you haven't considered is how a merge works when you have vectors of unequal size. You can't solve this problem until you ask yourself that question.

Something like this might be what you need. The important difference is that there is only one loop. The other difference is that I use `push_back` to build up the vector instead of trying to precalculate it's size. That's a little more natural for this algorithm I think.

```
vector<int> merge(vector<int> a, vector<int> b) 
{
    int n = a.size();
    int m = b.size();
    vector<int> c;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < n || i < m; i++)
    {
        if (i < n)
           c.push_back(a[i]);
        if (i < m)
           c.push_back(b[i]);
    }
    return c;
}
```

Comment: you can still use `c.reserve(n+m)` to avoid excessive reallocations

Comment: @rhalbersma, yes good point

Comment: and keep `i` local to the loop, and pass `a` and `b` by const reference

Comment: what is the difference between this piece of code and mine? your way is just another way of writing what i wrote.

Comment: @WilliamDuron I don't know how to say this, but my code is completely different from yours. One difference is that mine does a merge, while your's does not. Try both and you will see. If you can't understand why they're not the same then I think you need to review some C++ basics. How loops work, and how if statements work for instance.

Comment: @john explain the difference, my professor gave me the option of using this code, the one i used, and the one you used, saying they are practically the same, they will do the same job, but the one i am using is more efficient.

Comment: @WilliamDuron I'm afraid I don't know what you are talking about (or your professor). The routine that you called 'merge' actually does an append. If you look at your append and merge routines you can see that they are **letter for letter** identical, so how you can claim that one does a merge and the other does an append I don't understand. My merge routine really does do a merge. I can only think you misunderstood your professor.

Comment: @john i am actually asking for help, not a lecture. so don't bother commenting back, but thanks for your comments, have a nice day.

Comment: @WilliamDuron I am sorry, but I'm having a hard time understand where you are coming from. What it is that you are misunderstanding. It sounded to me that you were denying that my code did anything different from yours or even that your code was better. Oh well. Hope you get it sorted.